# %~dp0 not working when attempting to receive content from .txt file but working in other .bat files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was attempting to display the contents of a file if the user type /d for the first argument of my command.

However all it would display is 'The system cannot find the file specified.
Data:'

Using 'set "_path=%~dp0"' in my other batch files worked but not here, why, and how do I fix it?

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="/d" (
     set "_path=%~dp0"
     set data_txt=<%_path%user.txt
     echo Data: %data_txt%
)
```

Comment: `set data_txt=<%_path%user.txt` should be `set /p data_txt=<%_path%user.txt`, notice the `/p` switch

Comment: If you only want to display the file's content if the user select `/d` then why not try just this simple line? `@if "%~1"=="/d" @type "%~dp0user.txt"`

Comment: Thankyou everybody for your help, not only did I fix my code, I realized how bad I am at coding with batch lol